# Ubuntu will only boot in recovery mode

Tags: boot

I just built a computer and did a clean install of ubuntu 14.04 LTS and when I boot it while it is not in recovery mode, I get the log in screen for 11 seconds before the sreen goes black and my entire system crashes and restarts. The system boots fine if I boot it in recovery mode. This is a good temporary solution but I'd like to know if there is something I can do to permanently fix this. Also, during the installation process the computer crashed multiple times specifically during the time zone selection. Just a side note this is my first computer build. I looked for additional drivers for my apu but could not find any. Thanks in advance!

My specs are: Case- Rosewill microATX FBM-01
              MOBO- MSI A58-E33
              Power Supply- Setney bxps450-ps
              APU- AMD a8-6600k
              Hard drive- WD blue 1 tb
              RAM- crucial ballistix sport 4gb 1600 mt/s

Comment: To get further: While in recovery mode, do `cd /var/log/` and then `ls` to see the contents. Check at least the *.log files you find there (with `less filename`) for "fail" or "error" and "shut down" and other similar you can think of - add what you find to your posting.

Comment: "*during the installation process the computer crashed multiple times*" lots of crashes are not normal, I'm surprised it installed, something's not right. Does even the live iso run for a while without crashing? Maybe you need a (kernel) boot option like nomodeset, noapic, nolapic, etc... the iso should have some compatibility/troubleshooting options to try in it's menu (F6?).